# MySQL filtered backup & restore

Tags: mysql

I want to create a MySQL query to backup all my database, but filtered by a common value that is included in all tables, with the same column name.

I also want to restore the database for all tables with that same value, stepping over the previous rows with that value

1. Is this possible to do with just queries?
2. Can this be done by using a single file to backup and restore? (not multiple files each time I do the backup)

kind regards,

Comment: You can use the `--where` option to `mysqldump` to filter the dump. But the dump file contains `INSERT` statements, and they won't overwrite existing rows in the tables.

Comment: Ahh, there's a `--replace` option that makes it use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
mysqldump --where "colName = 'value'" --replace --skip-add-drop-table dbname > dumpfile.sql
```

Leaving out the table names after the database name makes it dump all tables. The `--where` option specifies the filter. `--replace` makes it use `REPLACE` statements rather than `INSERT` statements, so restoring the file will overwrite rows. `--skip-add-drop-table` makes it leave out the `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements, so it won't destroy the rest of the table contents when restoring.